# Angular 8 adding dynamic model

Tags: angular8

I have a card component

```
 @Component({selector: 'card',})
 export class CardComponent {
    
        @Input() title: string;
        @Input() isHistory: boolean;
        @Input() showMenu = boolean;
    
    }
```

And I want pass two properties dynamically. 'isHistory' and 'showMenu', which are defined as cardModels

general.component.html

```
<card  title="{{ configCard.header }}"
                [(ngModel)]="configCard.cardModels">
</card>
```

and
general.component.ts

```
export class GeneralComponent {
 private cardModels: {
      isHistory:  true,
      showMenu : false
    }

}
```

How to do this in angular 8, I tried with 'ngModel' but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`[(ngModel)]` is an atribute for binding form elements.
For parent-child interaction you'll need to use the @Input binding.

In your case

```
<card
      [isHistory]="cardModels.isHistory"  
      [showMenu]="cardModels.showMenu">
</card>
```

For further reading https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction